# How to add +30% to associated simple product price if an attribute = YES?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, html

If configurable product `attribute=yes` add 30% to `associated simple products` prices.

Have an attribute `afiliate` in my configurable product.

Need to add 30% to the `associated simple product price` if `afiliate` is yes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In default Magento, you set a base price for configurable products and have an additional price/fee for each option (= simple product). This could either be a fixed price or a percentage.

Go to any configurable product and then to the tab "Associated Products" at the bottom you see a block like this:

[image]

If you now set the price for a specific option, you can give it a different percentage. So if you make this "Affiliate" attribute a configurable option, you can set the option value "Yes" to a 30% additional fee.

Comment: We have an extension to show the SIMPLE PRODUCT PRICE in the front end. Also we have plenty of products and we need to make it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
```

or add observer and check for attribute